# very small Batch processing with spark

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, batch-processing

We are working on a project, where we need to process some dataset which is very small, in fact, less than 100 rows in csv format. There are around 20-30 such jobs that process these kinds of datasets. But the load can grow in future, and it can reach into big data category. Is it fine to start with spark for these extra-small load, so that system remains scalable tomorrow? Or should we write a normal program for now in java/c# that runs on schedule? And in future if load of some of these tasks becomes really high, switch to spark?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You absolutely should not do this in Spark. Spark demands a lot of complex infrastructure and just isn't worth it given a data size in the low thousands for rows total.

Comment: Thanks DemetriKots for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely fine,One thing to remember before running Job is to check memory and allocating memory based on size of data.
Say you have 10 cores , 50GB ram and initially you have csv files of 3kb or 1MB in size.Giving 50Gb ram and 10cores for 1Mb Files is a false approach,
Before you tigger the Job you should be carefull in allocating memory and number of executors.
For above csv files of 3Mb data you can give 2-cores at maximum and 5Gb of RAM to get job done.With the increase of size in data you can increase of usage of cores and memory.

Before you open sparkshell(Here I am using Pyspark and yarn as resource manager).This Can be done by example:

```
pyspark --master yarn --num-executors-memory <512M ,2G>
```

Thank you.